# IllegalStateException in ExposeInvocationInterceptor after upgrading to Spring 4.1.x

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading to Spring 4.1.4 and Spring Data Jpa 1.7.1 (from 4.0.2 and 1.5.1, respectively) I started to get IllegalStateException from ExposeInvocationInterceptor#currentInvocation()

At first I thought it could be somehow related to the following fix https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12351 but I got the same exceptions also with Spring 4.1.1.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Below is an excerpt from the exception stack trace:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress, and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute before ExposeInvocationInterceptor!
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ThreadBoundTargetSource.createObject(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:226)
at org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.getTarget(AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:187)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.getLockModeType(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:224)
...
```